# Television show/episode: future without blindness(?)

Tags: story-identification, tv

Some time in the past three years I happened to watch a show which was presented as a (fictional) documentary about a near future where blindness (or some similar kind of condition) had been cured. The 'documentary' focused on those remaining individuals who were born before the cure and how they didn't quite fit into society. Any thoughts?